# HP-UX 9: Backup filesystem using tar

Tags: filesystems, backup, tar, hp-ux

So I've got an HP-UX 9 box that I'm trying to backup, first to a tape with fbackup, to no avail, and now to a folder shared over NFS.  I'm using the command "tar -cvf /nfs/Results/backup.tar /" where the single '/' should mean that I want everything within the root directory to be backed up, but for whatever reason it's only backing up a certain directory within /dev/ and then terminating.  I get the feeling it doesn't like how I'm specifying the directory to be backed, so how might I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Your `tar` probably does not 'like' special files under `/dev` and then just errors out.

Backing up `/dev` just as-is is always problematic - e.g. think about reading from `/dev/zero` or a block device ...

With GNU `tar` you can easily exclude certain directories from your backup.

Or perhaps you can use some snapshot feature of your HP-UX root filesystem for backup.

Comment: So I removed the files it was bombing on, which were device files, but they were huge! One was 370MB.  After deleting those files, it got past dev without issues. Can't believe I didn't try this before :p  Thanks for the input, though!

Comment: On a related note, since my backup is of the entire system, it's including the NFS share I'm saving the backup to.  So I'm making a backup of my backup!  What would be the best way to exclude my /nfs/ folder? HPUX tar does not support the exclude command...